# JDBC batch for multiple prepared statements

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Is it possible to batch together commits from multiple JDBC prepared statements?

In my app the user will insert one or more records along with records in related tables. For example, we'll need to update a record in the "contacts" table, delete related records in the "tags" table, and then insert a fresh set of tags.

```
UPDATE contacts SET name=? WHERE contact_id=?;
DELETE FROM tags WHERE contact_id=?;
INSERT INTO tags (contact_id,tag) values (?,?);
// insert more tags as needed here...
```

These statements need to be part of a single transaction, and I want to do them in a single round trip to the server.

To send them in a single round-trip, there are two choices: for each command create a Statement and then call `.addBatch()`, or for each command create a `PreparedStatement`, and then call `.setString()`, `.setInt()` etc. for parameter values, then call `.addBatch()`.

The problem with the first choice is that sending a full SQL string in the .`addBatch()` call is inefficient and you don't get the benefit of sanitized parameter inputs.

The problem with the second choice is that it *may* not preserve the order of the SQL statements. For example,

```
Connection con = ...;
PreparedStatement updateState = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE contacts SET name=? WHERE contact_id=?;");
PreparedStatement deleteState = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE contact_id=?;");
PreparedStatement insertState = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tags (contact_id,tag) values (?,?);");

updateState.setString(1, "Bob");
updateState.setInt(1, 123);
updateState.addBatch();

deleteState.setInt(1, 123);
deleteState.addBatch();

... etc ...
... now add more parameters to updateState, and addBatch()...
... repeat ...

con.commit();
```

In the code above, are there any guarantees that all of the statements will execute in the order we called `.addBatch()`, even across different prepared statements? Ordering is obviously important; we need to delete tags before we insert new ones.

I haven't seen any documentation that says that ordering of statements will be preserved for a given connection.

I'm using Postgres and the default Postgres JDBC driver, if that matters.

Comment: You will never accomplish all this in a single round-trip, because of the COMMIT alone, let alone whatever the driver does in communicating with the database, which you know nothing about, let alone what TCP does in segmentizing and acknowledging segments, anyway. And in any case there is no particular advantage in a single round-trip, whatever you may think.

Comment: But you have a serious misunderstanding here. Nothing in a batch actually happens until you call `executeBatch()`. Then it all happens, and in order, But you are going to have to call  `executeBatch()` on all three `PreparedStatement` objects in some order defined by you: say `updateState.executeBatch(); deleteState;executeBatch(); insertState.executeBatch();`; on which all the UPDATES will happen first, then all the DELETES, then all the INSERTS. There is no way around this. (And of course none of it happens at all until the COMMIT.)

Comment: @user207421 If there are multiple child tables (7 in my case, but there will be more) then round trips make a big difference.  Assuming 5 ms latency per round trip, then we've bumped latency from 5 ms to 35 ms per parent record. That's a big deal if you're trying to do batches of 100 parent records.

Comment: Latency within a LAN is insignificant. My ping time to the other side of the world is 8ms. You should be concerned about the speed of the database operations, which is orders of magnitude longer: not trivia like this. Especially unimplementatble trivia.

Comment: But it's difficult to understand why you are updating a row you are about to delete.

Answer (score 1):

The batch is per statement object, so a batch is executed per `executeBatch()` call on a `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` object. In other words, this only executes the statements (or value sets) associated with the batch of that statement object. It is not possible to 'order' execution across multiple statement objects. Within an individual batch, the order is preserved.

If you need statements executed in a specific order, then you need to explicitly execute them in that order. This either means individual calls to `execute()` per value set, or using a single `Statement` object and generating the statements in the fly. Due to the potential of SQL injection, this last approach is not recommended.